# Algolia Ranking and Sorting not applying as expected

Tags: sorting, algolia

We're having a few dozen indexes with about ~2.5k records each. Now the ranking and sorting is something we cannot wrap our heads around. For most cases it works as expected, but there are a few records that don't make sense to us.

Search term: `i 16` (space before the 16)

The results are:

- Abox-i 160-16
- Abox-i 160-16²/sw
- Abox-i 160-L
- Abox-i 160-L/sw
- Abox-i SL-16²
- i 16-2,5²
- i 16-L

The most relevant results are the ones at the very last. While I understand that the first two are up there because of the two `16`, I don't understand why the remaining in the middle are above the actual, most relevant ones.

We cannot change ASC to DESC since that would mess up the rest of the search, which is just fine.

Also, we are not sure what this means, since we clear our indexes before filling with new data.

[image]

Here are a few screenshots of the settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anybody solve this mystery for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ranking formula is **sorting all results by `name`**, ascending (in alphabetical order), due to the `Sort-By` setting of your setup.

This is explained in [Algolia's documentation for sorting records by attribute](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/sorting/#sorting-by-attribute):

> The goal of attribute-based sorting is to ensure **all records which match the query appear in the order determined by the sort-by attribute**.

This means that when a query returns N results, the Algolia engine will return these N results sorted by name. This explains why all the records named `A****` are ranked higher than the records named `i****`.

If you want your Algolia results **sorted by relevance**, you should remove any `Sort-By` attribute.